# There is/are one or several apple/~s?

Tags: grammatical-number, there-is

To be clear, among

> There is one or several apple.
>
> There are one or several apple.
>
> There is one or several apples.
>
> There are one or several apples.

which is correct?

---

My guess:

[image]

Because of the *shortest distance* rule <sup>1</sup>, *apples* is correct as it is near *several*.

Though *there* seems to be near *one*, the actually object is *apples*, and thus *are* should be used.

Thus

> There are one or several apples.

is correct.

To make things clearer,

> There are one or several apples and a table.

illustrates the long connection between *there* and *apples* better.

<sub>1 Sorry, I do not know its English name. I just translate it from my language back.</sub>

---

By the way, I do not want to emphasize *at least one*.

Comment: Does [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33544/verb-agreement-with-subjects-of-different-grammatical-number) help at all?

Comment: Since you would say "There are one or more apples," by analogy "are" is correct. I would suggest changing the sentence to "There are either one or several apples." It sounds much better to me; I don't know why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is not a smooth phrase but of the choices "There are one or several apples" would be most common. See [this](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=There+is+one+or+several%2C+There+are+one+or+several+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22There%20are%20one%20or%20several%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:18805,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en) for examples.

"There is at least one apple" would be better.

Comment: The more frequent alternatives "There is at least one apple," and "There are one or more apples," mean something slightly different. If I heard somebody say "There are one or several apples," I would assume that there were **not** two apples.

Comment: It may be common, but it is in technical violation of the rule about verbs agreeing with the number of the nearer subject in disjunctive compound subjects, such as this one.