# What is the correct way to indicate a singular/plural that ends in (ies)

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography

I would like to know what the correct way to indicate a singular/plural pair is when the singular ends in *-y* and the plural in *-ies*.

With book you can use *book(s)* to indicate in writing how to form the plural from the singular, but with *party*, would you use *party(ies)* or *party(s)* or something else?

Is there a reference where rules are provided for this?

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93940/number-agreement-when-using-s-for-optional-plural) deals with this ‘optional *(s)*’, but does not mention how to add the *(s)* if a change in the base word also has to occur.