# Plural by adding (s)

Tags: parenthetical-plural

Is it okay to say

> Their aim  is to find which element(s) of the input  has(ve) the genuine impact on the output.

My question is concerned with the plural of  element(s) and has(ve).

Comment: 'Their aim is to find which input elements have the genuine output impact.' seems clearer to me.

Comment: I'd use "Their aim is to find which element/s of the input has/have the genuine impact on the output." if forced to.

Comment: So what is your question? Are you asking how to deal with the different verb forms required by your optional pluralisation of the subject?

Comment: If so, [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11380/when-a-sentence-uses-a-parenthetical-plural-should-the-rest-of-the-sentence-tre) would appear to be a duplicate.

Comment: Nigel J is right.  It is ludicrously bad style to write things like "(s)".  I hope this isn't for any kind of serious writing.  If you just use the plural, the reader will surely be intelligent enough to understand that it might turn out that only one element has genuine impact.  If you truly insist, just write something like "which element or elements of the input have".  Don't pollute your essay with ugly, unpronounceable parenthetical nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, I would suggest :

> Their aim is to find which element/s of the input has/have the genuine impact on the output.

Comment: But this is now writing advice. OP asks a genuine question; you give a workaround, which, although eminently sensible, leaves OP's question unanswered.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I shall edit that out, then.

Comment: OP is asking about the rules surrounding the device of shortening say 'I need to find which person or persons did this' to 'I need to find which person/s did this', when further complications arise.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I misunderstood. Edited now.

Answer (score -2):

"Their aim is to find which element(s) of the input has(ve) the genuine impact on the output "

**1st.** If there is more than one element, *"elements"* should be plural.

**2nd.** ...the input *(3rd singular person)* **has** the genuine...

I hope it helps.