# Should I pluralize based on an item in parentheses

Tags: grammar, parentheses

Which of the following two sentences is correct:

```
Jon (and Michael) is smart.
Jon (and Michael) are smart.
```

This example is clearly contrived but my question is whether the sentence should be grammatically correct when you erase the text in parentheses (`Jon is smart`) or should it be grammatically correct when read with the text in parentheses (`Jon and Michael are smart`).

Comment: Parentheticals do not count. See also previous related posts. Good Luck.

Comment: I just wouldn't use parantheses in sentences like this!

Comment: @TimFoster - Yeah, me either- Michael’s an idiot...

Comment: @Kris If you need to see how something happens to have been printed to get its grammar right, then you are doing it all wrong. Grammar is about the language itself, its syntax and its morphology, not about how someone or other set it out in writing or printing or Braille. Therefore if you cannot here it, it does not count.

Comment: The proper answer is to rewrite any such sentence to avoid the issue.

Comment: Very similar: [When a sentence uses a parenthetical plural, should the rest of the sentence treat it as singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11380)

Comment: @tchrist grammar/semantics of  "if you cannot **here** it" ?

Comment: @TrevorD Rephrasing is neither needed nor is the solution here.

Comment: @sumelic I summarized everything from that reference you cited into one sentence above. Need say more?

Comment: @TimFoster But that's not the question.

Comment: @Kris "Jon is smart, and so is Michael." would solve the problem if op wants the emphasis on John, with Michael as an afterthought. If that's not what op wants, then why include the brackets?

Comment: @TrevorD You seem to miss the point. What the OP wants is not how to construct the sentence, but given the structure whether to use the singular or the plural. Hope you get the drift.

Comment: @Kris I'm well aware that that is not directly what OP asked. But I'm also aware that (1) OPs sometimes want a solution to a problem, and one has to 'read between the lines' of what OP asked in order to ascertain the underlying problem; and (2) various contradictory comments & answers have been given - so OP hasn't got a clear answer to the Q. anyway.  Where is the harm in offering an alternative solution?  Op can ignore it if s/he chooses to.  Also rewording avoids the issue noted tchrist's comments that "parentheses cannot be heard".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note the use of is in this sentence: My friend (and her brother) is coming today. The subject is My friend. Despite appearances, parentheses are never part of the subject.

According to https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/commas/all-about-parentheses/

Comment: If you downvote, I'd appreciate knowing the reason. That way, I can improve it.

Comment: Grammar is a feature only of real language, which means that it is only about what can be spoken and heard, not about writing technology. Can you hear parentheses?

Comment: @DracoTomes Never mind the down votes.

Comment: The rather more prestigious [CMOS](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Usage/faq0180.html) concurs: 'A case such as this illustrates a broader category in which justice (and, therefore, injustice) no longer applies.' As does Garner (Garner’s Modern American Usage, third edition. Oxford University Press), a real grammar. But others have recommended that rephrasing is usually the best choice hereabouts, to silence all critics.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should **not**.

A phrase or sentence inside the paranthases is used to add some detail to the running sentence to make it better for the reader to understand without breaking the *flow* of it.

Therefore, it is completely a new sentence and should not participate in the grammar of the existing one because that would break the flow, which is the last thing we want.

Comment: Grammar is spoken not written. And parentheses cannot be heard.

Comment: @tchrist what do you mean? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Read it aloud to someone. Don't tell them anything about its typography. Ask them what sounds right.

Comment: @Infinity Right. However, to qualify as an answer and not just a comment, it needs to be substantiated further. Read the FAQ. Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris Thank you Sir/Ma'am. I am new here, can you please reframe the answer in your own words to show me how a perfect answer should be, in case you have sufficient time. Thank you

Comment: @Infinity Here it is: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/answering